# Does anyone offer free email/ssh provisions?

Tags: unix, shell

I wish to learn the UNIX SHELL can someone provide me with services such as these? SSH/POP etc?

Answer (score 3):

To expand on Zach's reply, I recommend getting a Live Distro that you can run from a CD/etc without installing to hard-drive. Perfect for playing about without affecting your existing OS.

Pick one from [www.livecdlist.com](http://www.livecdlist.com) - ordered by votes, so probably best to go for one near the top. :)

Comment: I would agree with this being a good way of learning, but would add in addition might be good to install a linux distro on a virtual machine, so that you can easily switch back and forward between your current OS without rebooting.

Comment: Yes, a VM is a good choice if your machine is powerful enough / etc.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a Windows PC and you can install software on it, try [Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/) This gives you a Unix environment and a bash shell.

Answer (score 1):

Have you had a look around [this list](http://www.red-pill.eu/freeunix.shtml)?

Comment: +1 for the great list, though many of the services have gone the way of the dodo =(

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of public/open access Unix systems (e.g. [SDF](http://sdf.lonestar.org/)) that offer free accounts which are usually quite restrictive (paid accounts provide more "rights", disk space, bandwidth, and access to more services). It's probably better to grab a free distribution of a Unix or Unix-like operation system and install it on your own computer. That way, you can play "administrator" and get your hands dirty.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to play around with the Unix environment without destroying your current install, you could try using virtualization. A program called [VirtualBox](http://www.virtualbox.org/) can let you run x86 operating systems in a contained environment, and if things go wrong, just delete the virtual machine and reinstall.

Or if you want just a shell, you could try [Rootshell](http://www.rootshell.be/), which will give you an OpenBSD based shell. For a Linux based shell, [Polarhome](http://www.polarhome.com/), can do that, as well as give you some other operating systems to play around with.

In my personal opinion though, I would try VirtualBox, because if you are just learning the shell, a GUI will be helpful when you need to fix or check on something that you might not know how to do in the shell.